# Dealing with exclaves in R tmap

Tags: r, dictionary, geography, tmap, cartography

I have a shapefile that includes an exclave (area that is not connected to the continuous main part), which causes the map to look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRpdb.png)

I tried to work around it by creating a dummy variable for the exclave and use tm_facets(), which leads to
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eiLY.png)

What I would want is for the labels "TRUE" and "FALSE" to disappear, and have the exclave in its own bounding box but inside the main map, slightly enlarged. I envision something similar to how many US maps handle Hawaii or many French maps handle the overseas territories

Comment: Please include full, minimal code with your questions. And you can edit your question to include the images inline with your question. Read this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you are looking for creating an inset map, maybe this can help: https://github.com/r-tmap/tmap/issues/541